# Displaying all products on sale with exp:resso store?

Tags: expresso-store

I am wondering if it is possible to show all on sale items with exp:resso store?

```
{exp:store:search search:on_sale channel="products" sort="asc" limit="12"}
...
{/exp:store:search}
```

This is what I've been trying to work with, but it's displaying every product ever entered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `search:on_sale="yes"` instead of `search:on_sale`.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that got things working. The docs should be more clear for that setting. It's not obvious. You might want to email them suggesting the change.