# Filtering products by on sale items

Tags: expresso-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying all products on sale with exp:resso store?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/displaying-all-products-on-sale-with-expresso-store)

It looks like it's not possible to pass an on_sale parameter to the products tag. This would be useful for pulling back a list of products that are on sale. Unless I'm missing something you currently have to pull back the full list and check the on_sale conditional, which is not as efficient and throws out the count and total_entries variables.

Could this be added to a future version if it's not already possible to do this somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Siebird. Just discovered that I'd missed both the docs and previous Qs! :-\  
  
However I'm finding that not all products on sale are being output. Code:  
  
`{exp:store:search channel="products" disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks|category_fields" status="open" search:on_sale="yes"}  
...  
{/exp:store:search}`  

Not all products marked as on sale are output. I have checked them and the ones that aren't output have an open status, a discounted price with the on sale checkbox enabled, so can't spot what the problem might be.

Comment: Oddly, the products not showing are out of stock and adding stock makes them show. So although the docs state that the default is to show all products, that doesn't appear to be happening.

Comment: Russ - are you sure you aren't using the in_stock parameter? If not, create a new question for this or email us and we will look into it.

Comment: I had to use in_stock="" to get it to output all products. Otherwise it defaulted to showing products in stock.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll take a look into this and see if we can get it fixed in a future version.